# Sigmajs Как выводить свои данные?

Tags: json, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Как сделать свой вывод из json файла? Нужно, чтобы у каждой точки фотка, имя и айди были.

```
ar i,
    s,
    img,
    N = 10,
    E = 50,
    g = {
      nodes: [],
      edges: []
    },
    urls = [
      'img/img1.png',
      'img/img2.png',
      'img/img3.png',
      'img/img4.png'
    ],
    loaded = 0,
    colors = [
      '#617db4',
      '#668f3c',
      '#c6583e',
      '#b956af'
    ];

// Generate a random graph, with ~30% nodes having the type "image":
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  img = Math.random() >= 0.7;
  g.nodes.push({
    id: 'n' + i,
    label: 'Node ' + i,
    type: img ? 'image' : 'def',
    url: img ? urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)] : null,
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random(),
    size: Math.random(),
    color: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
  });
}

for (i = 0; i < E; i++)
  g.edges.push({
    id: 'e' + i,
    source: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
    target: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
    size: Math.random()
  });
```